# How to use tf.get_collection() scope filtering in nested scopes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to retrieve a set of variables by defining them inside a scope and using the scope filtering in `tf.get_collection()`:

```
with tf.variable_scope('inner'):
    v = tf.get_variable(name='foo', shape=[1])
    ...
    # more variables
    ...

variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, 'inner')
# do stuff with variables
```

This normally works fine but sometimes my code is called by a module that's already defined its own scope `get_collection()` doesn't find the variables anymore:

```
with tf.variable_scope('outer'):
    with tf.variable_scope('inner'):
        v = tf.get_variable(name='foo', shape=[1])
        ...
        # more variables
        ...
```

I believe the filtering is a regex because I can make get_collection() work by prefixing my scope search term with `.*` but that's a bit hacky. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: You can try it retrieving the data values from the **ckpt.meta**  file with restore() function

Answer (score 0):

When I want to train a model, I use get_collection(), but before, I have to restore the model data as is shown in the following code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    last_check = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(tf_data)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(last_check + '.meta')
    print (last_check +'.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, last_check)
    ######
    Model_variables = tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES
    Global_Variables = tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
    ######
    all_vars = tf.get_collection(Model_variables)
    # print (all_vars)
    pesos=[]
    for i in all_vars:
        print (str(i) + '  -->  '+ str(i.eval()))
```

Comment: This is before I have created any checkpoints. To provide some context, I do this so that I can create one operator to reset a set of variables. Once  `tf.get_collection()` returns them in a list I can do:

`reset_mean_op = tf.variables_initializer(v)`

Comment: and if you look in the others GraphKeys variables??    https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys

Answer (score 0):

tf.get_collcetion(key, scope="outer/inner")